# Lookahead and Lookbehind regex

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

So I have this regex: `(?:\/p\/|$)(?:[^\/]*)(?<=-)(.*)(?=\/)`

and I want it to pull the id out of Ikea links but it seems not to work with Go. Can anyone help me with that? or is there a tool to just convert it?

I got it to work with all the other flavors but not Go.

https://regex101.com/r/74RITp/4 <-- with examples here

Comment: You just need `/p/[^/]*-(.*)/`. See https://regex101.com/r/74RITp/5

Comment: The `regexp` package does not support lookarounds. For more detail see https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may remove the lookarounds completely and rely on the capturing mechanism using:

```golang
/p/[^/]*-([^/]*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/74RITp/6). Note the leading and trailing `/` is part of the string pattern. *Details*:

- `/p/` - a `/p/` string
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char.

See the [Golang demo](https://play.golang.org/p/AcFwJzCPTHB):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/symfonisk-tischleuchte-mit-wifi-speaker-weiss-30435157/?tduid=d8b332c221610a36288c647f8959959f&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_name=generic&utm_term=conversion&utm_content=deeplink&utm_source=SmartApfel`
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(`/p/[^/]*-([^/]*)/`)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", regex.FindStringSubmatch(s)[1])
}
```

Output: `"30435157"`